# Is it a good idea SEO-wize to nest sections inside articles?

Tags: html, seo

I'm wondering which is the best way to go about grouping inside my site pages.

I'm using wordpress, by default it puts every page contents inside an `<article>` tag. In my "Services" page, I have different ones. I'm wondering whether it would be a good idea to group them in `section` tags so the structure would be:

```
<article>
<h1>services</h1>
<section>service 1</section>
<section>service 2</section>
<section>service 2</section>
</article>
```

Would this be good for SEO, or should I use a different structure?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<section>` tag is apparently new in HTML5, but certainly not necessary. The way search engines currently evaluate pages is through the use of `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc. ...as well as simply how a page's content is otherwise organized (i.e. in a logical, contextual manner and not littered with spammy keywords everywhere).

My short answer is that if you're coding in HTML5, it's consistent and there's no harm in using them, but I would **definitely** utilize heading tags and style them accordingly.